# How the way this kind of declaration help us?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seen there is a variable declaration now days popular,

the declaration is :

```
var object = object || {};

var array = array || [];

var number = number || 20
```

Such like this. i assume that, it is using the catching data's. but this is the only one useage of this? or is there any further advancement with this? else we need to declar the variables always this way? any one can explain me?

Comment: Your english needs a little work.  It is mostly to declare a variable with a pre-defined value, or as a constant (which could be just empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that so if the variable is already set, it takes its current value, otherwise a default value. Empty object, empty array, or 20, in the examples you provided. This way your code doesn't break if you try to use a variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

It is used to set the default value of a variable.

```
var object = object || {};
```

is same as

```
if (object) {
  var object = object;
} else {
  var object = {};
}
```

Comment: typo: `var object = {};` should rather be `object = {};`, otherwise the scope of `object` is really limited :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair not necessarily.  Depends on his scope.  Doing it your way will declare it as a global variable if it is not already defined.

Comment: @jeschafe yes, necessarily! otherwise the scope is limited to the `if`-block ... woha! so it is literally not the `same as` ... sry

Comment: I just mean it could be a temp variable.  Such as if(!object) { var object={}; object.something=someotherobject;object.something2=someotherobject2;}  Then you could iterate through the object in a loop.  You are correct that the scope is really limited, but it may be useful as a temporary holder of other information so you don't end up with a global variable if you don't want one.

Comment: @jeschafe that's not my issue! it's not about possibilities, it's simply the sentence `is same as` which obviously doesn't apply - so the translation of `var object = object || {};` is wrong - no matter what the possibilities of the *translation* might are ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair It's a matter of the scope that the OP is beginning with so I'll agree to disagree

Comment: @jeschafe i know that, due to the atm limited know-how about scopes, there's a significant need for the OP to get a lot of input about that topic - but that input should be valid! so your example (in one of your comments) should be somehow included (or made popular) and this answer should be correted - atm it is and it is not correct, even though the correct part is quite ... well, let's say, vague ... it should include a hint, **WHY** this is working - aka `|| is the or-operator, which used in this context is shorthand for ...` ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair What do you mean of scope? Javascript only has function scope, no block scope.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair you'll still be able to access the variable outside of the `if` block...

Comment: @xdazz thanks a lot for clarification! yes, it is true that the declaration gets moved to the top of the function - forgot about that. but, if you are accessing the variable `object` before the `if`-statement you'll get an undefined error - see @ http://jsfiddle.net/FhGTB/ ... anyhow, your translation, after double-checking, is now valid :) (http://jsfiddle.net/FhGTB/1/) sry ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yep, that's true. That is why you should declare all of your local variables at the top of function.